# tensorflow: an ops like matmul, with every combinations of elements between two arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow

an issue in tensorflow. 
there r two tensor

```
a=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
b=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
```

I can use

```
tf.matmul(a,b,False,True)
```

get a tensor like this

```
#[[a1b1 a1b2 a1b3 a1b4 …] 
#[a2b1 a2b2 a2b3 a2b4 …] 
#[a3b1 a3b2 a3b3 a3b4 …] 
#…]
```

but now, if I want to get a tensor like this

```
#[[a1-b1 a1-b2 a1-b3 a1-b4 …] 
#[a2-b1 a2-b2 a2-b3 a2-b4 …] 
#[a3-b1 a3-b2 a3-b3 a3-b4 …] 
#…]
```

or this

```
#[[tf.pow(a1,b1) tf.pow(a1,b2) tf.pow(a1,b3) tf.pow(a1,b4) …] 
#[tf.pow(a2,b1) tf.pow(a2,b2) tf.pow(a2,b3) tf.pow(a2,b4) …] 
#[tf.pow(a3,b1) tf.pow(a3,b2) tf.pow(a3,b3) tf.pow(a3,b4) …] 
#…]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain what `a1b1` etc. means? The tensors you specified are scalars so I suppose that are values that are fed serially to the placeholders?

Comment: @DocDriven : For example, after
`sess.run(c,feed_dict={a:[[1],[2],[3],[4]],b:[[1],[2],[3],[4]]})
c=tf.matmul(a,b,False,True)` 
I can get c as 
`#[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
 #[ 2.  4.  6.  8.]
 #[ 3.  6.  9. 12.]
 #[ 4.  8. 12. 16.]]`
because 
`#c[0][0]=a[0]*b[0]
#c[1][0]=a[1]*b[0]
#c[0][1]=a[0]*b[1]...`
it define by matmul. 
But now i need c as
`#c[0][0]=a[0]-b[0]
#c[1][0]=a[1]-b[0]
#c[0][1]=a[0]-b[1]...`
How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve using tensorflow `broadcasting` feature:

> #[[a1-b1 a1-b2 a1-b3 a1-b4 …]
>     #[a2-b1 a2-b2 a2-b3 a2-b4 …]
>     #[a3-b1 a3-b2 a3-b3 a3-b4 …]
>     #…]

```
# Subtract a and b transpose
c = a - tf.transpose(b)
```

**Output:**

```
#[[ 0. -1. -2. -3.]
#[ 1.  0. -1. -2.]
#[ 2.  1.  0. -1.]
#[ 3.  2.  1.  0.]]

# for input: a:[[1],[2],[3],[4]],b:[[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

> #[[tf.pow(a1,b1) tf.pow(a1,b2) tf.pow(a1,b3) tf.pow(a1,b4) …]
>       #[tf.pow(a2,b1) tf.pow(a2,b2) tf.pow(a2,b3) tf.pow(a2,b4) …]
>       #[tf.pow(a3,b1) tf.pow(a3,b2) tf.pow(a3,b3) tf.pow(a3,b4) …]
>       #…]

```
#form (i,j) index matrices and then apply tf.pow
i = tf.tile(a, [1, tf.shape(b)[0]])
j = tf.transpose(tf.tile(b, [1, tf.shape(a)[0]]))
power = tf.pow(i,j)
```

**Output:**

```
# index i              index j
#[[1., 1., 1., 1.],    [[1., 2., 3., 4.]
#[2., 2., 2., 2.],      [1., 2., 3., 4.]
#[3., 3., 3., 3.],      [1., 2., 3., 4.]
#[4., 4., 4., 4.]       [1., 2., 3., 4.]]

#Output
#[[  1.   1.   1.   1.]
#[  2.   4.   8.  16.]
#[  3.   9.  27.  81.]
#[  4.  16.  64. 256.]]
```